# Parse a log file to fetch some values in a line

Tags: regex, tcl

I am reading a log file where i am trying to fetch some values from lines which contains a substring  "edited by:" and ending  with " bye".

This is how a log file is designed.

```
Error nothing reported
19-06-2021 LOGGER:INFO edited by : James Cooper Person  Administrator bye.  //Line 2
No data match.
19-06-2021 LOGGER:INFO edited by : Harry Rhodes Person External bye.        //Line 4
.......
```

So i am trying to fetch:

```
James Cooper Person Administrator   //from line 2
Harry Rhodes Person External        //from line 4
```

And assign them to variables in my tcl program.

I am assuming the fetched lines are in a list name line2.
like

```
set splitList[$line2 ' ']
set agent [lindex $splitList 0]
set firstName [lindex $splitList 1]
set lastName [lindex $splitList 2]
set role [lindex $splitList 3]
```

I understand that having the fetched or extracted lines from log file in a list is not a good idea as they are unstructured input. Using  Tcl list functions can lead to weird things when they aren't in proper Tcl list format.

I am very new to tcl. And don't have much idea using regex in tcl.

So I tried extracting values from the matched line using regex. Suppose line2 is a variable holding the extracted matched line2 from the log file,

```
regexp -- {edited by:(.*) bye.$} $line2 match agent
```

I was able to get the expected output like below.

```
Person Harry Rhodes External
```

However, on this extracted string I don't know how I can further drill to get my variables assigned values. Any suggestion on this approach or any other functions which are present in tcl library which can help me with this task please let me know.

Updated the question by editing the log format. The format of the log file was not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To err on the safe side, I would modify the regex to look for whitespace (`[[:space:]]`) between words, using `*` (= *"any amount"*) and `+` (= *"at least one"*) as appropriate and storing each variable in a capturing group (surrounded by parentheses `()`):

```
edited[[:space:]]+by[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]+bye.$
```

Please note that `[^[:space:]]` matches any character except whitespace.

Regex101 demo: https://regex101.com/r/78l4HJ/1

Comment: I tried the expression but still doesn't seem to match it.

Comment: Ah seems the Tcl regex flavour is very limited. I'll need to modify the answer - which version of Tcl are you using?

Comment: Have now modified the regex for Tcl 8.1+ based on [this cheatsheet](http://www.wellho.net/regex/tcl.html).

Answer (score 0):

First off, taking apart the name of a person into its components is extremely difficult. For example, some people have a multi-word family name. (Yes, I know *specific* examples of this.) Other people put the parts in different orders. Can you avoid splitting the name?

The other parts of parsing that substring are easier as we can assume that `agent` and `role` will not have spaces in. The trick to this RE is that `\w+` matches a “word” character sequence, `\s+` matches a space character sequence (more robustly than a single space), and `.*?` matches anything, but as little of it as possible.

```
regexp {^\s*(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\w+)\s*$} $substring -> agent name role
```

OK, that's great for the substring, but what about the whole line? It's really just a matter of adjusting the anchors. (`\y` matches a word boundary.)

```
regexp {\yedited by:\s*(\w+)\s+(.*?)\s+(\w+)\s+bye\y} $line -> agent name role
```

It's often not a good idea to feed more than a line at a time into a regular expression search, not unless you need to. Fortunately your records are newline-delimited so that's not a problem here.

Comment: Ideally, you'd log user IDs and not names.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I need the name because we don't have username logged.Also i just realized that in our logs, we have some cases where people don't have any role. So,they are assigned a hyphen(-) value.Like below,

19-06-2021 LOGGER:INFO edited by:Person Jack Rudoplh - bye.

So the cases are varying and it became more difficult now working on an regex expression to meet these demands.

Comment: The solution is good. But i checked that my logs are having an extra space character before edited and space between colon (:) and by.  <space>edited by : <space> Person James Cooper Administrator bye. How can I incorporate this case